# Tramp configure can't find Emacs

Tags: tramp

I am trying to install a newer version (2.3.1) of Tramp than is currently running with my Emacs. When I run `./configure` in `tramp` ala the instructions [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Installation), I get the error

```
 checking for 24.5.1... no
 configure: error: no not found
```

My understanding is that somehow the script is able to see the version of my emacs (I confirmed this is the correct version) but is not able to find the Emacs folder/binary - not sure if that is exactly it as the configure script is quite large and complicated. What steps should I take to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `./configure --with-emacs=/path/to/emacs`